# Python ctypes: wraping c++ class with operators

Tags: c++, python, c, ctypes

I want to wrap a small test C++ class for use in python using ctypes. The class is called `Edge` and has a friend comparison (==) operator. I am having difficulty implementing the comparison feature in the wrapper python code.

A succinct `Edge` header is:

```
class Edge {
    private:
        int p1, p2;
    public:
        Edge(const int pp1, const int pp2);
        ~Edge(){};
        friend bool operator==(const Edge &e1, const Edge &e2);
};
```

The python wrapper I have written is:

```
from ctypes import *
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./libedge.so')

lib.Edge_new.argtypes = [c_int, c_int]
lib.Edge_new.restype = c_void_p

lib.compare_edge.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_void_p]
lib.compare_edge.restype  = c_bool


class Edge(object):
    def __init__(self, pp1, pp2):
        self.obj = lib.Edge_new(c_int(pp1), c_int(pp2))

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return lib.compare_edge(self.obj, c_void_p(other))
```

Where, Edge_new and compare_edge are C++ routines that are defined as:

```
#include "Edge.hpp"

extern "C" {
    Edge* Edge_new(const Int32 pp1, const Int32 pp2) { return new Edge(pp1, pp2); }

    bool compare_edge(Edge *e1, Edge *e2) {
        return *e1 == *e2;
    }
}
```

The constructor works fine. When I compare two edge objects `e1 == e2` I get the following typeerror:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "Edge.py", line 21, in <module>
    print e1 == e2   File "Edge.py", line 16, in __eq__
    return lib.compare_edge(self.obj, c_void_p(other)) TypeError: cannot be converted to pointer
```

I do understand what the error means, and most likely why something is going wrong, but I don't know how to fix it. I am compiling C++ code with gcc 4.7 and the python interpreter is 64 bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is, you're trying to cast a Python object to a `void *`, rather than the `void *` you already attached to that object's `obj` attribute.

It should be as simple as changing...

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return lib.compare_edge(self.obj, c_void_p(other))
```

...to...

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return lib.compare_edge(self.obj, other.obj)
```

The explicit call to `c_void_p` should be unnecessary, since you already declared the types in the line...

```
lib.compare_edge.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_void_p]
```

Comment: Brilliant! Can't believe I missed that. I've gonna have to live with this shame :(